# xargs with two command - mkdir and sed

Tags: bash, sed, xargs

I want to create catalogs and in the same line I want to change path and save it in the output file
I don't want to repeat code, so I tried:

```
cut -d ';' -f 1 tmp1 | tr '.' '/' | xargs -I %  bash -c 'mkdir -p %; sed 's/$/\/version/'% > output'
```

And I have a error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error got generated because you are using many `'`. In particular `s/$/\/version/` is outside any single quote.

`sed` is either working on a file either on the standard input. It cannot change a string passed as parameter. `printf` built-in command can be used to append `/version`.

Remarks:

- there is one name extracted for each line read from the `tmp1` file, so the names do not contain `\n`.
- according to the use of `cut` and `tr`, the resulting directories will not contain any `.` nor `;` char in their names.

What you are trying to achieve is this:

```
cut -d ';' -f 1 tmp1 | tr '.' '/' | xargs -I % bash -c 'mkdir -p "%" ; printf "%s/version/\n" "%"' > output
```

Note that special chars in names are going to break this above command-line: e.g. `'` (single-quote).

`cut` and `tr` can be replaced with only one `awk` which with `xargs -0` can be used to handle safely the names (separated with null char).

Give a try to this safe version:

```
awk -F\; '{gsub(/[.]/,"/",$1);printf("%s\0",$1)}' tmp1 | xargs -0 bash -c 'for f; do mkdir -p "${f}";printf "%s/version\n" "${f}";done' arg0dummy > output
```

`awk` script:

- `-F\;` defines `;` as field separator, so `$1` is the first field (before `;`)
- `gsub` is used to replace `.` with `/`
- `printf` is used to print the result and insert a final `\0` (null) char.

`xargs`:

- `-0`: Input items are terminated by a null character instead of by whitespace, and the quotes
     and backslash are not special (every character is taken literally).  Disables the end of
     file string, which is treated like any other argument.  Useful when input items might
     contain white space, quote marks, or backslashes.

`bash -c ...`:

- `arg0dummy`: it is not used but it is mandatory; see `man bash`.